# two equal signs (==) in anr not working

Tags: active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

I have added the following 2 entities to my Domain:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.LH269> Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(anr==leon)'
DistinguishedName : CN=Leon1,CN=Users,DC=LH269,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Jennifer
Name              : Leon1
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 942dd033-6414-471b-b142-77ac954c3d07
SamAccountName    : leon-s
SID               : S-1-5-21-2040647692-1963463148-3417863429-1151
Surname           : Leon
UserPrincipalName : Leon1@LH269.com

DistinguishedName : CN=Leon\, Jennifer,CN=Users,DC=LH269,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Jennifer
Name              : Leon, Jennifer
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : ff0aae88-83ad-4118-a76f-fdd90242ead5
SamAccountName    : leon
SID               : S-1-5-21-2040647692-1963463148-3417863429-1145
Surname           : Leon-Jarama
UserPrincipalName : Leon@LH269.com
```

When i execute the following query:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(anr==leon)'
```

I would expect to get only 1 response:  CN=Leon\, Jennifer,CN=Users,DC=LH269,DC=com

Why do i get 2 results ? In ANR documentation it clearly say when using anr==XXX:

```
You can force ANR to require an exact match on any of the attributes in the table by starting the value with the equal sign, "=" (so the filter has two equal signs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can force ANR to require an exact match on *any* of the attributes

"Any" is the key word here. Both of those accounts have attributes that are searched by anr that exactly match "leon".

```
Surname           : Leon
```

```
SamAccountName    : leon
```

Comment: Yes, but the surname is exactly "leon", which is why that account is included. Surname is one of the attributes that anr searches.

Comment: Is it possible to dismiss an attribute or declare the specific attribute on the anr algorithm?

Comment: Yes, in the documentation under [Add Attributes to the ANR Set](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx#Add_Attributes_to_the_ANR_Set), but you uncheck the 'Ambiguious Name Resolution (ANR)' checkbox instead of checking it.

Comment: But if you only want to search one or two attributes, you can do that by modifying your query to not use anr. Something like this: `(|(sAMAccountName=leon)(userPrincipalName=leon))`

Comment: I get it, the ANR attributes can be set specifically on the "server", I cannot force to ignore specific anr attributes in the ldap query itself. that would hurt the anr algorithm.. I need to disable that attribute in the "server" if i dont want it to be ANR attribute..

Comment: Exactly. You got it. :)